# How to use find with variable and wildcards

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a simple program that downloads multiple images from multiple pages of a website. When trying to implement folder creation that has a naming structure similar to how the website is layed out, I ran into issues. Below is a bare bones example of what I used to replicate the behavior of my other program.

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    # Sample inputs: 
    # http://testurl.com/post/1234
    # http://testurl.com/post/5678

    folder=""
    if [[ $1 == *"post"* ]]; then
        folder=${1##*/}
        folder=${folder//[$'\t\r\n ']}
    fi
    
    if [[ $(find "$HOME" -name "*$folder*" -print -quit) ]]; then
        echo 'Hi'
    else
        echo 'Bye'
    fi

    # Sample directories:
    # /home/user/1234
    # /home/user/0001
```

Everywhere I've looked tells me this should run perfectly. However, this does not run as it should and I've been at it for hours. Can anyone help me?

Bash version: GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: What do you mean by "does not run as it should"? What behaviour do you expect, what behaviour do you see?

Comment: what do you want to do in the first place?

Comment: @choroba I'm expecting to see "Hi" when the program finds a folder that contains the numbers at the end of the URL and "Bye" when it doesn't find one. I see "Hi" regardless of input numbers matching existing directory names

Comment: Try running it under `set -xv` to see what was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this simplifies the test whether `find` found something, using standard `grep` rather than bashisms:

```sh
if find "$HOME" -type d -name "$folder" -print -quit | grep .; then
  echo "Hi"
else
  echo "Bye"
fi
```

i also changed two constraints for `find`:

- only search for directories: `-type d`

  - so you don't get ordinary files
- only search for paths where the basename (the last componenent of the full path) matches `${folder}` exactly

  - so you don't get matches for the `/home/user/12345` or `/home/user/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/.saves-12350-localhost~`

for practical reasons (once the script is known to work), i would discard the output of `grep`, by redirecting it to `/dev/null`)

if the directories are all directly in "${HOME}", you could also add `-maxdepth 1` as the first argument to `find` (to not recurse into subdirectories).

so you end up with something like:

```sh
if find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$folder" -print -quit | grep . >/dev/null
then
  echo "Hi"
else
  echo "Bye"
fi
```

or simply use:

```sh
if [ -d "${HOME}/${folder}" ]; then
  echo "Hi"
else
  echo "Bye"
fi
```

Comment: Find was too broad and found firefox caches containing the numbers so the program wouldn't run because it kept saying the directory exists. Thank you for the grep output because I would've started ripping my hair out.

Comment: Thank you also for the extra detail! Gave me some inspiration for other features!